# Avoiding Duplicate Records in A Table asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Firstly, I register onto my webs site and I am then able to join a private group using username and a password. The problem is that if I am trying to insert into a group that I have already joined, a duplicate record comes up in my table.

So I have a Member Table(MemberId-PK, Username etc), an Assign Group Table(MemberId--FK),(GroupId--FK) and a Groups(GroupId--PK),Name,Password,Sport) Table.

Here is my code:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Tom\Documents\BIS\4th Year\FYP\FYP\Back-up\test2\FitnessForYou V1-08.01\FitnessForYou\FitnessForYou\App_Data\MembersData.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(*)FROM Groups WHERE GroupName='" + txtGroupName.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'");




        cmd2.Connection = con;




        int OBJ = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
        if (OBJ > 0)
        {

            con.Close();
            con.Open();

            cmd2.CommandText = "Insert into AssignGroups(MemberId,GroupId) Select Members.MemberId, Groups.GroupId From Members, Groups Where Members.Username= '" + lblRegistered.Text + "' And Groups.GroupName= '" + txtGroupName.Text + "'";



            Session["GroupName"] = txtGroupName.Text;




            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd2.Clone();
            Response.Redirect("GroupMembers.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Invalid username or password";
            this.lblError.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

This code inserts your record into the tabeo whether it has duplicates or not. How would I be able to check the database to see if you are already a member and hence give them a prompt without insert the record again.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text!**

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not reinvent the wheel.  You should use an existing, proven, authentication system.

Comment: Just a couple of small tips. You should store your sql connection string in your web config. Also remember to use try catch finally when opening connections, if something goes wrong and an exception is thrown you can close the connection in the finally. Good luck with your work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I have edited my answer above using cmd2.Connection = con. How would I be able to go about checking whether the record already exists before inserting?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding cmd2.Connection = con; before executing command.
No relation between command and connection in above code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my answer above using cmd2.Connection = con. How would I be able to go about checking whether the record already exists before inserting?

Comment: You can check if (OBJ==0) { insert code } else { record already exists code}. I think your code seems correct. Just change OBJ > 0 with OBJ == 0.

Comment: After changing that, it does stop duplicates but it also stops legitimate inserting when there are no duplicates. It's very close at this stage. Do you see anything else that I might add to resolve it?

Comment: Sorry, I may be wrong in previous comment. So you should undo if statement :) In your code you are already checking if a group exists. Like that control you should add another block if user and group couple already exists in AssignGroups table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a sql guy but here's a query you might want to run to check if a member is already assigned to a group.

```
  Select  Count(*) from AssignGroups where
  MemberId IN (Select MemberID from Members where Username='username')
  And GroupId IN (Select GroupID from Groups where GroupName='YourGroupName')
```

If it returns a positive value, the member is already assigned to the group, and so do nothing. 
Else, member is not assigned and you can run your Insert query.